# Почему у нас нету предупреждений при создании вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Заметил на enSO, что при попытке закинуть в окно много кода, вылетает предупреждение:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Так же, есть предупреждения об использовании форматирования кода

Comment: У нас не так много вопросов и посетителей, чтобы их так просто отсеивать :)

Comment: Так это же не отсеивание, а просто ненавязчивое  красное  предупреждение под редактором.

Comment: Ну это всего лишь шуточное предположение, реальной причины я не знаю

Comment: Не знаю как насчёт размера кода, но насчёт форматирования у меня предупреждение выскакивало. И оно было не просто "ненавязчивым", а не давало опубликовать ответ.

Comment: Может, это связано с тем, что на ruSO у вас много рейтинга и вам доверяют, а на enSO мало и не доверяют?

Comment: @andreymal я в инкогнито проверил и не заметил такого сообщения.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Я получал, когда спрашивал там

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я знаю, мы можем настраивать движок так, чтобы [регулярным выражением] отлавливать определенные шаблоны и показывать предупреждения, если что–то нашли. Вероятно, в настройках SOen есть «регулярка» для определения вопроса только с кодом, а у нас её нет.

Comment: Вероятно? Хотелось бы большей конкретики от сотрудника компании.

Comment: А почему мы не можем добавить разных регулярных выражений?

Comment: @AntonSorokin Можем. Все доп. настройки сайта добавляются как решения конкретных проблем. Если у нас есть проблема с вопросами, где есть только код, ее стоит описать на Мете отдельным вопросом, привести примеры, попытаться измерить числено (или описать как это могу сделать другие участники). Далее, все желающие смогут высказаться за или против. Мы все проанализируем, и по результатам активируем (или не активируем) эту функцию движка.

Comment: Движок и технология принятия решений явно запланированна для их максимального отсеивания :)